# How to extend the size of virtual sd card to an Android AVD virtual machine without losting existing data?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've a AVD (from Android studio 4.0.1) that keep running for a while, and filled up the virtual SD card in that configuration. I'd like to extend the virtual SD card so that I can use the same AVD, WITHOUT losting the exist data on that virtual SD. Is that possiable? and how to do it? Is there a way or tools to do so?

NOTE: Modify the size in the AVD manager doesn't work!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can just edit your AVD's Settings and edit the SD card's size: [AVD Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLKOp.png)

Comment: That will not causing the data lost for the virtual sd card? I think I did that before and cause the virtual sd card reinitilized. Hum... maybe I can give it a try again after back the current image.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. There's even warning message when trying to modify the virtual sd size: "Modifying the SD card size will earse the card's content!..."

Comment: I see, well i recommend you to create a new AVD. It's not a good practice to rely on the data of a single device, and even less if it is an emulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).